# Determine a Web Application's version of AngularJS

Tags: reconnaissance, angularjs

For reconnaissance, is there a definitive way to determine the version of AngularJS that a web application uses.

Other tools, such as wappalyzer and builtwith show the frameworks, but not the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the version number from the JS file itself.

Header of the current `angular.js`:

```
/**
 * @license AngularJS v1.0.6
 * (c) 2010-2012 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
 */
```

You can search for this file using the console of your browser as well.

Comment: And now I see it. Somehow I missed this before.